# Laravel 4 - How to set up multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 3 tables: member, team and teammember. Each team can have multiple members, but they must not be repeated. Also, members can be in many teams at the same time.

I want to setup the table teammember so that you can't add the same member to the table twice. In my migration I have this:

```
Schema::create('teammembers', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('team_id');
    $table->integer('member_id');
}
```

I know how to setup the foreign keys by themselves, but in my case I need the restriction to only affect the combination of both keys, for the reasons explained before.

Comment: `$table->unique(['team_id','member_id'])` will create compund unique index, but still `attach` method will try to add a new row to the pivot table, so you need to be careful

Comment: A composite primary key can be achieved by this: `$table->primary(['keyone','keytwo']);`

Comment: @deczo, your solution was finally the right one, can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$table->unique(['team_id','member_id'])` will create compund unique index, but still attach method will try to add a new row to the pivot table, so you need to be careful.